# What's wrong with the following (Robinson-) nonstandard proof?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

Note: I do not know for sure that it's wrong, but have a strong suspicion, as the authors implicitly mentioned it but in the end chose another (more elaborate) proof.

Let $\hat S$ be a superstructure. 
Let $^*$ denote the transfer of an element of $\hat{S}$ via the transfer principle. 
Let $\varphi[x_1,...,x_n]$ be a statement in the variables $x_1,...,x_n$ and $A$ a set, and $A, \varphi[x_1,...,x_n]\in\hat S$.

To show:
$^*\{(a_1,...,a_n)\in A : \varphi[a_1,...,a_n] \text{ is valid} \} =
\{(b_1,...,b_n)\in {^*A} : {^*\varphi[b_1,...,b_n] }\text{ is valid} \} $

The proof:
Let $A_0 := \{(a_1,...,a_n)\in A : \varphi[a_1,...,a_n] $ is valid $\}$. 
 
Since $A_0 \subset A$ it follows that $A_0\in \hat S$. Therefore the statement 
$\forall x_1,...,x_n \in A: \bigg((x_1,...x_n)\in A_0 \Leftrightarrow \varphi[x_1,...,x_n]  \bigg)$ 
is a valid formula of $\hat S$. By transferring it, we get:
$\forall x_1,...,x_n \in {^*A}: \bigg((x_1,...x_n)\in {^*A_0} \Leftrightarrow {^*\varphi[x_1,...,x_n] } \bigg)$

And since $^*A_0 \subset {^*A}$ (follows from $A_0 \subset A$ ), the transferred formula tells us which elements are in $^* A_0$ :

$$
\{(b_1,...,b_n)\in {^*A} : {^*\varphi[a_1,...,a_n] }\text{ is valid} \}  
= {^*A_0} = 
{^*\{(a_1,...,a_n)\in A : \varphi[a_1,...,a_n] \text{ is valid} \}}
$$

---

The book it's from is "Nichtstandardanalysis by Landers, Rogge" (a German book).

The transfer principle so far is (let $\hat S$ and $\hat W$ be two superstructures): 
$$ \begin{align}
&(1) & {^* \hat S }&=  \hat{W} \\
&(2) & {^*s} &= s, \text{ for } s\in S \\
&(3) & \varphi\in\hat S  \text{ valid} &\Leftrightarrow   {^*\varphi}\in\hat W  \text{ valid}
\end{align} $$

(where in $(3)$, $\varphi$ is a propositional formula)

Comment: I corrected a typo.  There are some additional (similar) typos to correct.  Otherwise the proof is OK.  Which book are you referring to?  Perhaps they are only working with a restricted form of the transfer principle.

Comment: In both the statement you transferred and the result after you tranferred it, all the $a_i$'s should be $x_i$'s. Otherwise, the proof looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake:

My proof assumes that for every tuple $(a_1,...,a_n) \in A$, the elements in the tuple $a_1, ..., a_n$ are in $A$ as well.

---

Hmm... yes, you're right. If we go by the definition $\hat S = \bigcup_{v\in \mathbb{N}} S_v$, we get $A\in \hat S \Rightarrow A\in S_v \text{ for some }v\in\mathbb{N}$, therefore $A\subset S_v$, and hence $^*A \subset  {^* S_v}$. 
So if we correct the statement  
$\forall x_1,...,x_n \in A: \bigg((x_1,...x_n)\in A_0 \Leftrightarrow \varphi[x_1,...,x_n]  \bigg)$ into $\forall x_1,...,x_n \in S_v: \bigg((x_1,...x_n)\in A_0 \Leftrightarrow \varphi[x_1,...,x_n]  \bigg)$, my argument is void.

Comment: This should be true by "transitivity".  Why do you assume it is a mistake?

Comment: So, should I correct the formula in the initial question? In the end it's a mistake, even though not the one I'm looking for